# The password-reset link from laravel cannot reach my SPA password-reset page

Tags: vuejs3, quasar-framework, laravel-10

I am using a Quasar/vuejs SPA with laravel as a backend.
I can ask for a password reset link and I receive it.
Nevertheless when using this link I end in the home page of my SPA instead on the passwor-reset page.

The link is like this
http://localhost:3000/password-reset/376ecca99a228d274f22ea45de20d0d8d986c3ff5860def1b7cafd92cb5dba27?email=john.doe@somedomain.org

Here is my router/index.js file

```
import { route } from 'quasar/wrappers'
import { createRouter, createMemoryHistory, createWebHistory, createWebHashHistory } from 'vue-router'
import routes from './routes'
import { useAuthStore } from "../stores/auth";

export default route(function (/* { store, ssrContext } */) {
  const createHistory = process.env.SERVER
    ? createMemoryHistory
    : (process.env.VUE_ROUTER_MODE === 'history' ? createWebHistory : createWebHashHistory)

  const Router = createRouter({
    scrollBehavior: () => ({ left: 0, top: 0 }),
    routes,

    history: createHistory(process.env.VUE_ROUTER_BASE)
  })

  Router.beforeEach(async (to) => {

    // redirect to login page if not logged in and trying to access a restricted page
    const publicPages = ['/login', '/register', ' / '];
    const authRequired = !publicPages.includes(to.path);
    if (/\/password-reset\/[a-w0-9\?@\.]+/.test(to.path)) { authRequired = false }
    const authStore = useAuthStore();
 
    
    const user = localStorage.getItem('user')
    
    if (authRequired && user === null && authStore.authUser === null) {
      return ({ path: '/login' })
    }
    //fetch authenticated user in back-end
    if (authRequired && user && !authStore.authUser) authStore.fetchUser()



  });

  return Router
})
```

and my router/routes file

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: () => import('layouts/MainLayout.vue'),
    children: [
      { path: '', component: () => import('pages/HomeView.vue') },
      { path: 'persons', component: () => import('pages/PersonsScrollView.vue') },
      { path: 'banks', component: () => import('pages/BanksView.vue') },
      { path: 'events', component: () => import('pages/EventsView.vue') },
      { path: 'general-expenses', component: () => import('pages/GeneralExpenses.vue') },
      { path: 'general-incomes', component: () => import('pages/GeneralIncomes.vue') },
      { path: 'cassette', component: () => import('pages/CassetteOperationView.vue') },
      { path: 'bank', component: () => import('pages/BankOperationView.vue') },
      { path: 'periods', component: () => import('pages/PeriodsView.vue') },
      { path: 'register', component: () => import('pages/RegisterView.vue') },
      { path: 'login', component: () => import('pages/LoginView.vue') },
      { path: 'forgot-password', component: () => import('pages/ForgotPasswordView.vue') },
      { path: 'password-reset/:token', component: () => import('pages/PasswordResetView.vue') },
      { path: 'about', component: () => import('pages/AboutView.vue') },
    ]
  },

  // Always leave this as last one,
  // but you can also remove it
  {
    path: '/:catchAll(.*)*',
    component: () => import('pages/ErrorNotFound.vue')
  }
]

export default routes
```

In fact its behave as if restarting the app.

**EDIT 2**
I discovered that, in quasar.config.js, changing vueRouterMode from 'hash' to 'history' fixed this issue. Nevertheless a new issue appeared : I cannot refresh the page without ending in a page not found error.
What can I do ?

**EDIT 3**
I also discovered that inserting a # just after the domain.ex/ makes the link work properly. Thus the question how to make laravel send a link with this hash ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally keep the vueRouterMode at 'hash' and changed the reset link in the App/Providers/AuthServiceProvider file.

```
ResetPassword::createUrlUsing(function (object $notifiable, string $token) {
            return config('app.frontend_url')."/#/password-reset/$token?email={$notifiable->getEmailForPasswordReset()}";
        });
```

I am not sure this is the good fix but it works.